# Crystal report Error in Hosting server of Plesk

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I am using vs2008[asp.net,c#] and sql sever2008 to develop a web application.

Where I created a Crystal Report but its generating error on hosting server.
Locally its executing perfectly.

Error Message:

> Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are insufficient
>   or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed correctly.   Please
>   install the appropriate Crystal Reports redistributable
>   (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the Crystal Reports
>   runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required.  Please go to
>   http://www.businessobjects.com/support for more information.
>
> Line 45:         ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
>   Exception Details:
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LoadSaveReportException: An
>   error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports
>   runtime.

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you did not install the same version of the runtime on the server as you used to design the report, or you are trying to deploy to a 64-bit server. The Crystal for VS2008 [must run in 32-bit mode](http://scn.sap.com/community/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio/blog/2011/01/07/how-to-deploy-a-crystal-reports-net-web-application-on-a-64-bit-operating-system) (even the 64-bit package).

If your web server is 64-bit, follow the advise in the linked article (build as x86 and run App Pool as 32-bit).

Alternately, upgrade to VS2010 or 2012.